# Ошибка сборки конкретного проекта

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

На серверной машине установлен gitlab-14.4.2-ee, неожиданно появилась ошибка сборки одного из проектов, надеюсь на вашу помощь, ибо который час не могу разобраться самостоятельно...

Лог сборки:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.10.0 (54944146)
  on Builder 64UoDUuL
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image docker:stable ...
Authenticating with credentials from /root/.docker/config.json
Pulling docker image docker:stable ...
Using docker image ... for docker:stable with digest ...
Preparing environment
Running on runner-64uoduul-project-13-concurrent-0 via vps...
Getting source from Git repository
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/.../.../.git/
Created fresh repository.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 504 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 504
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Как я понял из других решений, проблема в размере репозитория, который gitlab-runner не может склонировать (размер репозитория - 1.44ГБ).

Пробовал:

- Увеличить баффер гита на машине - `sudo git config --global http.postBuffer 104857600`
- Установить стратегию клонирования `clone`, вместо `fetch` (в настройках проекта, файле gitlab-ci и системных переменных раннера).

Предполагаю, что нужно изменить какие-то настройки конкретно раннера, чтобы они применились в контейнере, но какие и как именно - не знаю.

Возможно необходимые для помощи файлы:

1. Конфигурация раннера (config.toml): https://pastebin.com/i0a9VytS
2. Конфигурация сборки проекта (.gitlab-ci.yml): https://pastebin.com/gQEEyqPN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась не в размере репозитория, как я предполагал (удалил объёмные файлы - собираться снова не стало).
В конечном итоге просто создал новый проект и перенёс файлы - сборка заработала.